# Como faço para contar a quantidade de registros, onde registros iguais são agrupados e equivale a apenas um, e impor uma ordem ao mostrar

Tags: php

Tenho a tabela de relação com as colunas **autor** e **time**.

Preciso contar a quantidade de registros que o autor tem, sendo que os registros agrupados por autor e time conte como apenas 1, e depois exibir.

Exemplo:

**Autor -------- Time**

Gabriel ------- X

Gabriel ------- X

Gabriel ------- Y

João ---------- Z

João ---------- Z

João ---------- Z

No exemplo, onde o autor é Gabriel e o time é X seria contado apenas como 1 registro, o mesmo para João. Sendo assim, ao exibir na ordem decrescente ficaria:

Gabriel = 2 registros

João = 1 registro

---

Não consigo passar disso:

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT *, COUNT(autor) AS total FROM aa_usuarios_treinamentos_rel WHERE time>'$timeRanking' AND status='true' GROUP BY autor, time ORDER BY total DESC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo o cenário que você apresentou, a query básica ficaria assim

```
SELECT autor, count(DISTINCT time) FROM tbl GROUP BY autor
```

Veja em funcionamento no SQLfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c5220/1

### Explicação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse primeiro exemplo, está os dados reais, da tabela, `mauro` tem dois registros, `felipe` um registro e `jesus` um registro também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o `COUNT(DISTINCT time)` recebo os valores reais da query

Comment: Desde já, muito obrigado!
No meu caso, precisaria que os registros de mauro contasse como apenas 1 por ter os times iguais e caso mauro tenha um terceiro registro com o time 2, por exemplo, contasse 2 registros.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6baa9/1

Nesse caso eu precisaria mostrar Gabriel 2, João 1 e Pedro 1, em ordem decrescente.

Comment: Atualizei o link, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Perfeito! Não conhecia esse método que você utilizou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Caso tenha te ajudado, marque como melhor resposta, para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.